# mismatched tag. Expected: </link>, when loading .html with jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm loading a .html file onto a div with id `#content`. Upon loading the external .html file I get the following error: `mismatched tag. Expected: </link>.`

Here's the html file I'm loading:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/landing.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel-header">
        <p>Lokacija</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Institut Jožef Stefan</p>
        <p>Jamova 30</p>
        <p>1000 Ljubljana</p>
        <div id="map-canvas">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-header">
        <p>Kontakt</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p id="info">informacije:</p>
            <a href="#"><span class="ion-email icon-link-mail"></span></a>
            <a href="tel:+38614773304 "><span class="ion-ios-telephone icon-link-phone"></span></a>     
        <p>izposoja:</p>
            <a href="#"><span class="ion-email icon-link-mail"></span></a>
            <a href="tel:38614773304"><span class="ion-ios-telephone icon-link-phone"></span></a>
        <p>bibliografije:</p>
            <a href="#"><span class="ion-email icon-link-mail"></span></a>
            <a href="tel:38614773247"><span class="ion-ios-telephone icon-link-phone"></span></a>       
        <p>vodja knjižnice:</p>
            <a href="mailto:luka.sustersic@ijs.si"><span class="ion-email icon-link-mail"></span></a>
            <a href="tel:38614773258"><span class="ion-ios-telephone icon-link-phone"></span></a>       
    </div>
    <div class="panel-header">
        <p>Delovni čas</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Pon-čet: 8.00-17:30</p>
        <p>Pet: 8.00-17:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-header">
        <a href="http://www.cobiss.si/scripts/cobiss?command=CONNECT&base=50108"><p>Katalog</p></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

If I try removing the `<head>` tags, I get another error `not well formed`. Is there another, more proper way to do this? Should I just be linking all the css I'll be needing for everything I load onto my main page?

Comment: thanks for downvoting without commenting, really helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `link` tag like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/landing.css" />
```